# When using Tomcat and Spring security, is it possible to remember login credentials across webapp restarts?

Tags: tomcat, deployment, spring-security

I'm using tomcat 6.0.32 in a development environment with Spring Security (3.0.5).  My problem is that every time my webapp restarts because of a class change I have to also login again. Is there a setting somewhere that will allow the login credentials to bridge between webapp restarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Spring Security documentation on remember-me: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html